Securing JWT tokens against attackers
I use JWT in an ASP.NET Core Web API application. For JWT, I need a secret, which I currently store in appsettings.json. It looks like this:
"Jwt": {
    "Secret": "cB7lN2sz3H9wI5pAJ8fgkLzV0Q4yxXMiRSO6rTKP1tE7mdjFZCpvWGuoDbhYaeqJnMVwiX5UFz4t8NYsQBoL3rlc20PGfMkj1HvT9pqRbDdOEJZmKaU6gSyWbVx8CnI7T0xywZ2mLI4pk3A9vgHeD5PoFN8jQK1X6sruYRhO0eWtxM3BVzZ9nLD4yfpA7qlUki2Sc6mHJ5XboGrQCVwIwxa9tgPB2sKjRyuM1ZvF7Ylnzhe4H8qo3k"
},

A potential attacker who gains access to my server could now read this secret from my appsettings.json. If the attacker is now in hold of this secret, the attacker can create any JWT tokens for my application.
To tackle this problem, I would now use a singleton pattern. To do this, I would first generate a static class that has a method to generate random strings.
This would look like this:
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.Utils
{
    public class RandomStringGenerator
    {
        private static readonly char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray();
        private static readonly Random random = new Random();

        public static string Generate(int length)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(length);

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var randomIndex = random.Next(chars.Length);
                stringBuilder.Append(chars[randomIndex]);
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}

Then I need a JWTSecretProvider (singleton). This would look like this:
namespace MyApp.Utils
{
    sealed class JWTSecretProvider
    {
        private static string _secret = null!;
        private static JWTSecretProvider _instance;
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();

        private JWTSecretProvider()
        {
            _secret = RandomStringGenerator.Generate(200);
        }

        public static JWTSecretProvider Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new JWTSecretProvider();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public string GetSecret()
        {
            return _secret;
        }
    }
}

If I now need to access the JWT secret, e.g. when starting the server or when a client requests a JWT token after authentication, I can access it as follows:
JWTSecretProvider.Instance().GetSecret()

What do you think about this approach?

You're confusing terminology here. What you have in your appsettings is not a JWT but a key used in the process of generating a JWT. Sensitive information should never be stored in appsettings. Instead consider something like Azure Key Vault or some alternative.

You can store them in environment variables. Environment variables can avoid storing application secrets in code or local configuration files, and accessing environment variables requires higher permissions than reading files.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows#environment-variables.

However, it should be noted that environment variables are usually stored in unencrypted plain text. If the computer or process is compromised, untrusted parties can access the environment variables. You may need to take additional measures to prevent the disclosure of user secrets.

Since the JWT Secret is a secret that has to be specially secured, I have come to the conclusion that my approach is not the correct one. As Peppermintology already mentioned in his comment, the recommended solution is to store a JWT Secret in an Azure Key Vault or something similar. I will consider this solution for my problem. Thanks to Peppermintology and everyone else who helped here.

Just to clarify a few points here, you said:

If the attacker is now in hold of this token, the attacker can create any JWT tokens for my application.

This isn't really true.  First of all, the JWT already appears to be encrypted, so it's possible that the attacker would not be able to figure out what is inside.  Even if the attacker can figure out where, for example, the claims section resides, any attempt to alter it would not work.  This is because the JWT contains a checksum on itself, to ensure that it has not been tampered with.  So your attacker would fail to gain access after hacking the JWT, because the server would figure out that the new checksum does not match the value contained within the JWT.

I think I need to explain something here. There are two tokens at JWT. One token, a randomly generated string, is in the appsettings. I am concerned with this one. Not the JWT token that the client receives. I need the token in the appsettings to generate the tokens for the clients. How do I secure the token in the appsettings correctly? Is my approach good for this?

So basically you're asking whether to store het JWT secret in appsettings.json, or in another manner?

@WiseDev yes. Is my approach a good one? I am storing the JWT secret in a singleton class and I am creating the secret on server start. Is this a good approach?

Good 'enough' as long as you're sure that it stays secure in there.
But of course, one can always improve storing secrets, using techniques like Vaults etc.
